# How to close calender when date is selected using Angular material Datepicker when using mat-datepicker-actions

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I'm using a normal Angular Material Datepicker (Angular 13), but I added some action buttons:

- one to clear the date
- one to set the date to 'infinity'
- the ok button (**which I want to get rid of**)

See my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-13-starter-x1xj4z-wzqxfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The clear button and 'infinity' button work fine. Once clicked, the date is cleared or set and the popup closes.
Perfect!

However, selecting a date works only by selecting the date and pressing the ok button.

**What I want:**
Selecting the date closes immediately the popup while setting the date. Just like the behaviour there exists without mat-datepicker-actions.

Any one knows how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be the answer, but it works:

```
@ViewChild(MatDatepicker) picker: MatDatepicker<any>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.picker.openedStream.subscribe((event) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.picker['_componentRef'].instance._calendar._userSelection.subscribe((event) => {
                console.log('Element selected')
            })
        },0)
    });
}
```

Comment: Confirmed! works indeed.
Thx

Comment: If it can't be done the way it should, it should be done the way it can.